# Will Roadster ever encounter Mars?

Tags: spacex, mars, orbit, falcon-heavy, tesla-roadster

During it first closest approach to Mars, it was a mere 5 million miles away from the red planet. According to [observer.com](https://observer.com/2020/10/tesla-roadster-starman-space-fly-by-mars-elon-musk/#:%7E:text=The%20Roadster%20was%20originally%20sent,in%20about%2010%20million%20years.), it's ultimate fate will be to crash into the Earth or Venus. However, since it is in a Mars crossing orbit, it may eventually encounter Mars. However, obviously, if it has crashed it can not encounter Mars. So, will Roadster ever encounter Mars?

Comment: https://www.whereisroadster.com/

Comment: That is the first place that I checked. Didn't give me anything useful.

Comment: The precise numerical simulation of the trajectory of the Roadster under the influence of the Sun, Earth, Venus, Mercury and Jupiter and Saturn over a very, very long time is impossible. So we can't know if the Roadster will ever encounter Mars after a million, billion or trillion of years.

Comment: Well, what about within the time that we can predict? @Uwe

Comment: The Starman has [Horizons id -143205](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/api/horizons.api?format=text&MAKE_EPHEM=NO&COMMAND=-143205). You can make distance plots using the link in my answer here: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/49267/16685 (Mars has id 499).

Comment: Are you suggesting "However, obviously, if it has crashed it can not encounter Mars…" means that a crash is not an encounter? If so I suggest the Question belongs not to Space Exploration but to English Language Usage…

Comment: A crash on another planet is not an encounter with Mars @RobbieGoodwin

Comment: Sorry but it is; in this case, it's an extreme example of "encountering a problem." Whether or not any kind of crash testing is a desirable part of this mission, the Question seems to assume that the plucky explorer isn't designed to make a close approach so what does leave but a controlled landing… or is there an "encounter" of another kind?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Roadster will have a close encounter with Earth in 2091 which will alter its orbit, but it is very hard to predict exactly where it will end up as its orbit will be somewhat chaotic due to the gravitational influence of Venus, Earth and Mars. Calculations suggest that the Roadster will remain in orbit for tens of millions of years before hitting a planet.

There is a 6% chance of it hitting Earth and a 2.5% chance of hitting Venus in the next million years. After 3 million years, the odds of an Earth crash rise to 10%. In the longer term, the Roadster has a 50% chance of lasting a few tens of millions of years.

*[Don't panic: The chance of this space-traveling sports car hitting Earth is just 6% in the next million years](https://www.science.org/content/article/don-t-panic-chance-space-traveling-sportscar-hitting-earth-just-6-next-million-years)*

Comment: Question, how close will it get? @Slarty

Comment: Probably a little closer than the Moon and observable with a good telescope.

Comment: If I'm understanding the Rein et al. article correctly, they ran 240 long-term simulations and none of them resulted in a collision with Mars, which the authors say "is statistically consistent with the conclusion that at most a few percent of
realization will impact Mars or Mercury." So it's possible for it to hit Mars, but quite unlikely.

Comment: That is odd considering it is launch on a Mars-aiming trajectory

Comment: It's a little strange, but the trajectory will be continually adjusted by gravitational effects especially during close approaches. It is possible that the 2091 close approach (or even some other approach) might totally redirect it.